# flutter circular progress indicator not showing in appbar

Tags: dart, flutter

i am creating a project where i need to show a progress bar in the appbar.the code is given below

```
bool loader_saver=false;
return Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text("add data"),
    actions: <Widget>[
      loader_saver?
          new CircularProgressIndicator()
      :
      new FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _add_Data();
          },
          child: new Icon(
            Icons.save,
            color: Colors.white,
          ))

    ],
  )
```

here is the onpressed method

```
void _add_data(){ 
final _formstate = _form_key.currentState;
if (_formstate.validate()) {
  _form_key.currentState.save();
  setState(() {
    loader_saver=true;
  });
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried https://flutter.io/debugging/#visual-debugging ?

Comment: not yet..but can you provide some code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will show your CircularProgressIndicator in appbar, change it as per your requirement

```
actions: <Widget>[
new Container(width: 60.0, height: 20.0, color: Colors.lightGreen,
child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),)]
```

Comment: thanks it is the right answer..can you please tell me how can i change the circular progress indicator color.

Answer (score 6):

Old thread but for anyone reading now:

I'm guessing that it wasn't showing up because in the default material theme the appBar background is the exact same color as the circular progress indicator.

But, even when you change the color, putting a CircularProgressIndicator in the appBar is hard because the bar will want to stretch the things inside it. See [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/52945). This is how I got it to look just like an action button and follow the correct theming:

```dart
 class ProgressRefreshAction extends StatelessWidget {
   final bool isLoading;
   final Function() onPressed;

   ProgressRefreshAction({
     this.isLoading,
     this.onPressed,
   });
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     if (isLoading) {
       final theme = Theme.of(context);
       final iconTheme =
           theme.appBarTheme.actionsIconTheme ?? theme.primaryIconTheme;
       return Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
         Padding(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 12),
           child: Container(
             width: iconTheme.size ?? 24,
             height: iconTheme.size ?? 24,
             child: CircularProgressIndicator(
               valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(iconTheme.color),
             ),
           ),
         ),
       ]);
     }
     return IconButton(
       icon: Icon(
         Icons.refresh,
       ),
       onPressed: onPressed,
     );
   }
 }
```

```dart
 //build(context) {
 return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       title: Text("MyApp"),
       actions: [
         ProgressRefreshAction(_isLoading),
       ],
       body: //...,
     ),
```

Comment: Thanks solved my issue about CircularProgressIndicator size in appbar

Comment: Nice. BTW you can shrink the hierarchy by one level if you replace the `Padding` with `margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 12),` on your `Container`

Answer (score 3):

i got the answer...thanks all of you for your response..here is the solution.

```
new Theme(
    data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(accentColor: Colors.yellow),
  child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks you are having `bool loader_saver=false;` as a local variable inside `build` method. It should be a `state` variable.

As you are calling `setState` you are having the above code inside `StatefulWidget`.

```
class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
 bool loader_saver=false; // add this line (state variable)

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 // bool loader_saver=false; remove this line (local variable)
```

Stateful widgets will get **rebuild** only for `state` variable change. Not for local/global variable change.

Comment: nop..I declared it outside widhet build method..it's not the exact answer

Comment: Is the control going inside `if (_formstate.validate()) {`?. If yes, could you please give some more code.

Answer (score 0):

Could you verify or change the color of the `AppBar` or `CircularProgressIndicator` i remember that they have the same default color the blue one.

Please before do something else verify that.